# Avoid inserting any blank rows in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010

I had posted a thread a while back about avoiding adding blank rows into the database. Before when something was to click add row it would automatically add a blank row into the database regardless if the user canceled the new row. I figured it out but now came to a new issue. If the user decides to reload the page(F5) while editing the new row, it will add a blank row into the database, thats a no no for my situation. Can anyone help me figure out how to avoid that?

Below is my insert code:

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Insert") //- this is needed to explain that the INSERT command will only work when INSERT is clicked
        {
            gv.DataBind();

            DataTable d = dbcon.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS ORDER BY ID DESC", "ProjectCISConnectionString");

            string transCode = "", fundCode = "", BSA_CD = "", DP_TYPE = "";

            if (d.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                transCode = d.Rows[0]["TRANS_CD"].ToString();
                fundCode = d.Rows[0]["FUND_CD"].ToString();
                BSA_CD = d.Rows[0]["BSA_CD"].ToString();
                DP_TYPE = d.Rows[0]["DP_TYPE"].ToString();

                if (transCode.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    dbcon.Execute("INSERT INTO CIS.CIS_TRANS (ID,TRANS_CD) VALUES(CIS.S_CIS_TRANS.nextval,'')", "ProjectCISConnectionString");

                    gv.DataBind();
                }
            }

            gv.EditIndex = gv.Rows.Count - 1;

        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Cancel")
        {
            DataTable d = dbcon.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS ORDER BY ID DESC", "ProjectCISConnectionString");

            string transCode = "";

            if (d.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                transCode = d.Rows[0]["TRANS_CD"].ToString();

                if (transCode.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    dbcon.Execute(string.Format("DELETE CIS.CIS_TRANS WHERE ID = '{0}'", d.Rows[0]["ID"]), "ProjectCISConnectionString");

                    gv.DataBind();
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say "When a user tries to reload the page while editing" do you mean when the user hits F5 while editing the form..?

Comment: Yes or when they just select the url and click enter.

Comment: Why do you call `gv.DataBind();` right at the start?

Comment: That was a actually mistype. Since I kept changing my code to fix my first problem which was adding a blank row on click(did not want this, only wanted to add a row when all information was filled), I took it out on my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid inserting blank row by the user, you need validators. Add `RequiredFieldValidator` to the insert template:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valFieldName"
< ControlToValidate="txtFieldName" ErrorMessage="FieldName is missing" />
```

In your method check if `Page.IsValid == true` before you insert to the database.

EDIT:
If you want to avoid postbacks completely, you can insert the whole grid into an `UpdatePanel`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GrdiView>
        ....
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now when the user hits F5 he just reload the page again and not posting back an insert command.

Comment: In this situation is the validator necessary? Because I have requriedfielvalidators on every textbox already. My situation is to just avoid inserting a blank row if its rreloaded(F5)(every other way of stopping a blank row is taken care of).

Comment: What do you mean by F5? is the user inserting one row and then hit F5?

Comment: Im just clarifying F% because it caused confusion for another user. F5 reloads the page, and if someone is adding a new row and its in editing form and they decide to reload the page, it loads back with a blank row inserted into the database. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: You can insert your the grid inside `UpdatePanel`

Comment: could you provide me with a deeper explaination please.

Comment: Thanks Amiram that worked with F5. But if the user selects the URl and clicks enter, blank row still gets added. If user X's out the page, the blank row still gets added.

Comment: Very strange. Can you put a breakpoint and see from where you method is called?

Comment: Hello @AmiramKorach korach, Incase you were wondering I fixed the issue threw a !postback statement I wrote in my form load

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you try to bring too much logic into one part of code. You put data base logic into button commands. Imagine the user just spams this button. That'd cause huge amounts of empty rows.

Try this approach: divide your database logic and your UI logic (e.g. **MVVM**). That's a common pattern, today.

Imagine you created all your objects and now the user hits the "save" button (that might also happen through changing a row - whatever). After the save command is executed your view model (the logic behind the view) could e.g. validate your data. So you could expand the functionality on your UI much easier (as said: validation or similar stuff).

If you'd like to do this with your current code, every expansion would blow it up more and more - and it doesn't take too much time till maintaining this code is horrendous.

After everything in your VM happend (validation etc.) the transaction command into your DB could happen (something like myEntities.Save()). And this method provides that your business objects get correctly transformed into SQL and stored in your database.

That was just a very brief explanation of the MVVM pattern, but that seems like the only proper solution here to me.